# What is the fastest way to update a field on thousands of records?

Tags: data-loader, sobject, data

I need to create a new checkbox field on an SObject, and I would like the original value to be true. Setting the **default** value of the field to true only applies to new records.

What is the fastest way to update the checkbox field to **true** on thousands of existing records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

**Option 1**

This provides you more control as only what you export will be updated

1. Export the ID and New Checkbox field to a css for all records
2. Change the values in the CSV to true
3. Import the file using data loader

**Option 2**

Quick and easy but new records added during the process will also be updated to true even if the user that added the record unchecked it.

In dev console keep executing this (replacing with actual API names) until no records are returned

```
YOURObject__c[] recs = [Select YOURCHECKBOX__c From YOUROBJECT__c Where YOURCHECKBOX__c = false LIMIT 2000];

for(YOUROBJECT__c rec : recs)
   rec.YOURCHECKBOX__c = true;

update recs;
```

You can adjust the limit to whatever your org will tolerate given its existing code base up to 10000.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Can I simply run this within an execute anonymous window? (Option 2)